# Django basic url slugifying issues

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to slugify my urls in my Django application. I have read many documents but I am still not sure how to do it better. I have two questions:

1. How to call the same view for two different urls?
   I would like to call home view for both www.mysite.com and www.mysite.com/index.html

   ```
   (r'^$', 'myapp.main.views.home')
   (r'([-\w]+)$', 'myapp.main.views.home')
   ```

   The code above sounds good but of course it raises an error as home view expects 1 parameter but 2 is given. How can I resolve this?
2. I have so many apps and they all have their own urls.py file. I was handle them as including their urls file to the root urls.py as

   ```
    (r'^warehouse/', include('myapp.warehouse.urls')),
   ```

In that way, urls seems like www.mysite.com/warehouse/blabla/
However, I want to slugify them as www.mysite.com/warehouse_blabla.html
Slugifying is not hard but how can I resolve such url and redirect it to the blabla view in warehouse app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first problem, you would be better off using a redirect for the `index.html` URL (better for SEO etc.)

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.main.views.home')
    url(r'^index.html$', redirect_to, {'url': '/'}),
)
```

Regarding the second issue, your `urls.py` file is just a set of regular expressions, so you have control over the URL scheme you want to use:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^warehouse_(?P<slug>[_w]+).html$', 'warehouse.views.warehouse_detail'),
)
```

That said, I think you would be better sticking to the usual convention of slashes